# node - invalid array length

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node v0.12.4.
When I run the following code with `node --max-old-space-size=8192 test.js` it gives me the error `FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - process out of memory`

```
var a = new Array(200000000);
console.log(a.length);
```

However if I change the size to 300000000 I don't get any error. What's going on here? Is there some command line argument aside from `--max-old-space-size` I need to change?

Comment: My first guess was that the first size was slightly less than the biggest 32-bit integer, and the second slightly bigger, but there's one too few zeros for that to be the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, I actually can't recreate this in v0.10. v0.11 segfaults.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Node.js heap memory limit for single object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231808/node-js-heap-memory-limit-for-single-object)

Comment: Sounds like it was [introduced in 0.11.15](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9181) and it's still open.

Comment: There is something fishy here, why would 300 000 000 not give you the same warning?  Does the console print the correct length when you use 300 000 000?

Answer (score 10):

V8's heap size is limited to 1 GB for 64 bit and 512 for 32-bit machine, but Buffer objects exist largely outside the heap. you can expand the memory use up to 1.7 GB in 64-bit and ~1 GB in 32-bit machine.
You can try this.

```
--max-old-space-size=3000  --trace-gc-verbose
```

you can print the trace to know about the memory use.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling Typescript to ES2017+ might solve this issue.

Sources:
[NodeJS memory growth - Memory leak in (system)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875158/nodejs-memory-growth-memory-leak-in-system/58990710#58990710)
https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/824

Answer (score -1):

There is a limit of memory.64bit Machines can use about 1.6gb.This is the limit of V8 compiler.
this links maybe can help you

[Configuring v8's memory management to be smart for a node.js process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586705/configuring-v8s-memory-management-to-be-smart-for-a-node-js-process)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/BQ5dSm8lITQ