# Node.js memory error FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, sails.js

I am running sails.js instance using sails 0.10.5. I stored a few objects in memory.

I frequently met the following error:

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - process out of memory.

It seems that some one has met this and reported that this is [introduced in node.js v0.11.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520505/node-invalid-array-length). As far as I can tell from [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9181), it is still an open issue.

To avoid it, I installed node v0.11.14 and runs sails v0.10.5. However, this problem still happens.

Could someone tell me when this error happens in Node and points me to the direction that how I can avoid it?

Comment: The V8 update mentioned in that issue was only applied in v0.12.x. You shouldn't be using v0.11.x anyway (at least anymore) since it's unstable and v0.12.x is available. Try installing node v0.12.7 and see if the problem persists.