# FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

Error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[873:0x1020aa000]    47109 ms: Scavenge 2107.9 (2131.9) -> 2092.1 (2131.9) MB, 0.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.999) allocation failure 
[873:0x1020aa000]    47231 ms: Scavenge 2107.9 (2131.9) -> 2092.1 (2131.9) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.999) allocation failure 
[873:0x1020aa000]    47353 ms: Scavenge 2107.9 (2131.9) -> 2092.1 (2131.9) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.999) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x27af028cfc7d]
Security context: 0x00a9d921d971 <JSObject>
    1: push [0xa9d9205831](this=0x00a92dc86431 <JSArray[112813858]>,0x00a9f2d5fdf1 <String[17]\: \n                >)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0xa92dc86471] [0x00a9bba025b1 <undefined>:~1] [pc=0x27af02959ff7](this=0x00a9051847e1 <JSGlobal Object>,0x00a92dc86531 <Object map = 0xa982312831>,0x00a9f2d4f6a9 <JSFunction exports.escapeXML (sfi = 0xa9f2d4edc9)>,0x00...

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x100060e87 node::Abort() [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000614f5 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x10017a687 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x10017a628 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x100437638 v8::internal::Heap::UpdateSurvivalStatistics(int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x10041de6a v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x10041d781 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 8: 0x1003dce56 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::ConvertElementsWithCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::ElementsKind, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
 9: 0x1003dcd0c v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::GrowCapacityAndConvertImpl(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
10: 0x1003db82a v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::Add(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, unsigned int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
11: 0x1005068dc v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
12: 0x100505a38 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
13: 0x10060fd43 v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
14: 0x100612c8c v8::internal::Runtime_SetProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.1/bin/node]
15: 0x27af028cfc7d 
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am getting this error every time I run my app.js file and click on a page, it tries to load for a minute without success and then crash. I know this question been asked before.

However, I have tried:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

I also tried:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js
```

and then run my app.js and problem still the same. I am not sure where my exported variables go, cannot find the .bashrc file anywhere etc. I am not even sure what's wrong, I am a bit new into coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node - invalid array length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520505/node-invalid-array-length)

Comment: This usually means that you're getting into an infinite loop in your code or something alike. Try to use V8 profiler to spot the problematic spot

Comment: Updated post with the full error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520505/node-invalid-array-length/65988860#65988860 answers here might help

Answer (score 6):

ANSWER:

I managed to solve it, I had an infinite loop working in the background as @alfasin suggested.

Comment: how did you find the loop?

Comment: It's probably a while loop, just do a project-wide search for `while` and make sure none of them will never terminate, if you still can't figure it out make a post on stackoverflow with all the different loops @katzenhut

Comment: @notacorn - thank you, but i was hoping for something more tool-like, like the V8-Profiler mentioned in the questions comments. Manual code analysis tends to be quite slow...

Comment: you could console log unique indicators in every loop maybe @katzenhut

Comment: I do have infinite loops in my application, which are called every X second. But they shouldn't be causing a problem like this. How do I find the loop that causes this problem?