# Invalid array length allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        obj.push("It's nice to work at Bass Pro Shop!"); 
    }

    return obj;
}

function validate(reason) {
    return reason.split(' ').length < 3
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tohFY.png)

I'm receiving this error when trying to run my JS:

> FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I've checked other similar posts that say to increase the memory size f.x., `node --max-old-space-size=16000 yourFile.js` or from [FATAL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330641/fatal-error-invalid-array-length-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-mem) to my script they both don't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you storing in your array?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't know where the image of the code disappeared, but it can still be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrzP.png

Comment: @0stone0 I'm new and I've corrected it with only the output now.

Comment: @Felix Kling I've added the output and storing nothing in array with obj = ['']

Comment: @Swiffy I removed it b/c it's not ideal to post the code apparently

Comment: @HiddenBoi69 It is encouraged to always post the code, but don't post it as an image, because others can't run and test it if it's an image. Please post the code as text and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to write your code down. You shouldn't be posting images of code.

Anyway, the problem lies here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    obj.push("It's nice to work at Devoteam!");
}
```

You are looping the same array to where you push more data inside the loop, thus the loop will never end and the array size becomes too large.

Comment: @ggorlen I wrote the code by hand, which OP originally posted as image. I've also submitted an edit request to the original post with my manually written code. The original image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYrzP.png

Comment: @HiddenBoi69 Try this one here https://pastebin.com/jem1RVHw It will give you the same FATAL ERROR, which you just need to fix by doing something to that push inside the loop. I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do, so I don't know what should be done to fix it.