# Getting error on processing array of 20000 in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

What is the maximum assignable length of an array in node.js? Why do these errors occur?

"FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

This error occurs when I execute this code.

```
const answer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 20000; j++) {
    answer.push(1);
  }
}
```

I think it means that the length that can be assigned to the array is exceeded.
Then, what is the maximum allocation length of an array in node.js?

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30815771/7574023) out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a strict limitation for memory usage in the V8 JavaScript engine.
the default are limits of ~512mb for 32-bit and ~1gb on 64-bit.

you can modify it like this for example:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourNodeFile.js
```

This will change the limitation to something like 4GB

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much !! :)